# Spring Boot - How to disable @Cacheable during development?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el, spring-cache

I'm looking for 2 things:

1. How to disable all caching during development with Spring boot "dev" profile. There doesn't seem to be a general setting to turn it all off in application.properties. What's the easiest way?
2. How to disable caching for a specific method? I tried to use SpEl like this:

   ```
   @Cacheable(value = "complex-calc", condition="#${spring.profiles.active} != 'dev'}")
   public String someBigCalculation(String input){
      ...
   }
   ```

But I can get it to work. There are a couple of questions on SO related to this, but they refer to XML config or other things, but I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and this uses auto-configuration.

I don't want to over-complicate things.

Comment: add `spring.cache.type=NONE` to your `application-dev.properties`.

Comment: `spring.cache.type=NONE` doesn't switch caching off, it prevents things from being cached. i.e. it still adds 27 layers of AOP/interceptor stack to your program, it's just that it doesn't do the caching. It depends what he means by "turn it all off".

Comment: for ignoring cacheManager usage in Cacheable  you need to use `NoOpCacheManager` bean as primary. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586253/5456789

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The  [David Newcomb comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917159/spring-boot-how-to-disable-cachable-during-development) tells the truth :

> `spring.cache.type=NONE` doesn't switch caching off, it prevents things
>   from being cached. i.e. it still adds 27 layers of AOP/interceptor
>   stack to your program, it's just that it doesn't do the caching. It
>   depends what he means by "turn it all off".

Using this option may fast up the application startup but could also have some overheads.

**1)To disable completely the Spring Cache feature**

Move the `@EnableCaching` class in a dedicated configuration class that we will wrap with a `@Profile` to enable it :

```
@Profile("!dev")
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CachingConfiguration {}
```

Of course if you already have a `Configuration` class that is enabled for all but the `dev` environment, just reuse it :

```
@Profile("!dev")
//... any other annotation 
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class NoDevConfiguration {}
```

**2) Use a fake (noop) Cache manager**

In some cases, activating `@EnableCaching` by profile is not enough because some of your classes or some Spring dependencies of your app expect to retrieve from the Spring container a bean implementing the `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` interface.
In this case, the right way is using a fake implementation that will allow Spring to resolve all dependencies while the implementation of the `CacheManager` is overhead free.

We could achieve it by playing with `@Bean` and `@Profile` :

```
import org.springframework.cache.support.NoOpCacheManager; 

@Configuration
public class CacheManagerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile("!dev")
    public CacheManager getRealCacheManager() {
        return new CaffeineCacheManager(); 
        // or any other implementation
        // return new EhCacheCacheManager(); 
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public CacheManager getNoOpCacheManager() {
        return new NoOpCacheManager();
    }
}
```

Or if it is more suitable, you can add the `spring.cache.type=NONE` property that produces the same result as written in the   M. Deinum answer.

Comment: @Alexandar Petrov Thank you for the fast feedback.  I don't know how to link to a comment, I fixed as I could.

Comment: Option 2 is the same as specifying `spring.cache.type=NONE`.

Comment: @M. Deinum Very probably.  Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: Using `@Profile` is not optimal because it requires you to hardcode profiles, of which there might be plenty. The recommended approach is to use a property to enable/disable a feature, which can then be configured within profile-specific properties files, without having to change the code.

Answer (score 79):

The type of cache is by default automatically detected and configured. However you can specify which cache type to use by adding `spring.cache.type` to your configuration. To disable it set the value to `NONE`.

As you want to do it for a specific profile add it to that profiles `application.properties` in this case modify the `application-dev.properties` and add

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
```

This will disable caching.

Comment: What about my second question using SpEl? There are some specific methods that I don't want caching for during development.

Comment: The [davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56901878/1298031) answer is a best answer. It explains exactly the Spring behavior and the good solutions.

Comment: The davidxxx answer doesn't answer to using SpEL in the `@Cacheable` for specific cases, the davidxxx answer is just too broad... @PaulNUK's answer seem to understand that.

Comment: Sidenote: you can put this in your `application-junit` profile and use `@ActiveProfiles("junit")` in all of your tests. This will deactive the caching for any tests, preventing kept states between test runs (which you will have otherwise when using `@Cachable`). If you wan to test the caching in one test explicit, you can annotate the testclass as follows to active caching only there: `@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.cache.type=")`

Comment: Value should be lowercased: ```none```

Answer (score 7):

If you have just a default profile and don't want to go through creating a dev and prod profiles just for this, I think this could be a very quick solution for your project:

Set this in your `application.properties`:

```
appconfig.enablecache=true
```

Based on your requirements, you can change it to `true`/`false`.

Now, when defining your @Caching bean, do this:

```java
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(@Value("${appconfig.enablecache}") String enableCaching) {
    if (enableCaching.equals("true")) {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager();
        //Add your Caching Implementation here.
    }
    return new NoOpCacheManager();
}
```

When property is set to `false`, `NoOpCacheManager()` is returned, effectively switching off your caching.

Comment: This is the better approach than the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

For your second question do something like this:

Write a method that determines whether or not a particular profile is active (environment is your injected Environment)

```
boolean isProfileActive(String profile) { 
   return Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains(profile);
}
```

then use that for your spel condition on the cacheable annotation

Answer (score 1):

In any class you want to globally enable or disable your caching, on a per method basis, you can do the following, which allows you to control at the class level how your methods are cached.

You can change it in `application.properties` with `my.cache.enabled=true`. This setup currently defaults to it being enabled.

Of course then you can change it in `application-dev.properties` as well, and set it to a different value. The advantage of this approach is it lets you make this more complex if you need to for some reason, on a per method basis as well.

```
public class MyClass {

  @Value("${my.cache.enabled:true}")
  public String isMyCacheEnabled;

  public boolean isMyCacheEnabled() {
    return (isMyCacheEnabled == null) || isMyCacheEnabled.equals("") || Boolean.valueOf(isMyCacheEnabled);
  }

  @Cacheable(
      cacheManager = "myCacheManager",
      cacheNames = "myCacheKey",
      condition = "#root.target.isMyCacheEnabled()",
      key = "#service + '-' + #key")
  public String getMyValue(String service, String key) {
    // do whatever you normally would to get your value
    return "some data" + service + key;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use resilience4j-spring-boot2 dependency with
org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer.
This solution will work with the latest Spring-boot version 6.x.
it worked for me.

**Below are code snippet:**

**Pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Cache config class:**

```
package com.redis.sample;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CachingConfiguration implements CachingConfigurer   {  
@Override
public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
return new CustomCacheErrorHandler();
}
}
```

**CustomCacheErrorHandler class:**

```
package com.redis.sample;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {
 
@Override
public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
//do something as per usecase
}

@Override
public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
//do something as per usecase
}

@Override
public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
//do something as per usecase
}

@Override
public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
//do something as per usecase
}
}
```

**CircuitBreakerConfig.java config class:**

```
package com.redis.sample;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker;
import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerRegistry;
@Configuration
public class CircuitBreakerConfig {

@Bean
  public CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry() {
    io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig config = io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
     .failureRateThreshold(6)
        .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(2)
        .slidingWindowSize(5)
        .minimumNumberOfCalls(5)
        .build();
    return CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(config);
  }
 
@Bean
public CircuitBreaker defaultCircuitBreaker() {
  io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig config = io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
      .minimumNumberOfCalls(2)
      .build();
  return CircuitBreaker.of("default", config);
}
}
```

Comment: how are you binding the circuit breaker configuration with the custom cache error handler?