# How to prevent caching in spring boot

Tags: caching, spring-boot

I have a gradle project and I am using spring-boot in my backend and for the front-end Angular 2.
Every time I do a get-Request after add or delete, the IE does not call the get-method. He takes the array from the cache.

I have already found a solution client side. I have put the headers:

```
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0'
```

in my Request. And then it works.

But I tried to solve this problem server side. I found in the internet, that you can prevent caching if you just add

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
```

in your application.properties. But this is not working.

Did I forgot anything else?

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplicationextends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

UIController:

```
@RequestMapping("/service")
public interface MyUIController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value= "/getBooks", produces="application/json")
    public List<Books> getBooks(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response);
}
```

RestController:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController implements MyUIController {
  public List<DomainEntity> getDomains(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
return myUIService.getBookss(request, response);
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class MyUIService {
public List<Books> getBooks(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    ResponseEntity<List<Books>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
        UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).build().encode().toUri(), 
        HttpMethod.GET,
        requestEntity, 
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Books>>(){});

    return responseEntity.getBody();    
}
```

Comment: `spring.cache.type` is for spring Caching support. It has no relation to the caching headers you are after...

Comment: is there another way? what does the value none means then? I have read this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917159/spring-boot-how-to-disable-cachable-during-development. In fact this is your post ;)

Comment: As mention it is for Spring Cache not for caching headers...

Comment: You can't fix this on the backend, as the caching is happening in the browser. Look into the docs on the cache-related headers you added.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum mentioned, `spring.cache.type` is for caching support which is entirely another spring feature.

However according to [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-cache-control), one can use this java configuration to enable cache-control:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        // ...
        .headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

This will automatically add the necessary cache-control headers.

Comment: where does WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ? I have a spring boot application and it can't find a reference to that class.

Comment: Oh, I had to add spring-boot-starter-security as a dependency.