# @Cacheable with condition for method arguments

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-el

I read from spring `@Cacheable` docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#condition--)
that `condition` can specify conditions on method arguments using SpEL.

I have been trying the same out but failing. Here is my method:

```
public static final String myStr = "4";
@Cacheable(condition="#!req.id.equals("+myStr+")")
public Response myCall(Request req){}
```

and here is my `Request` POJO:

```
public class Request{
 private String id;

 public String getId(){
  return this.id; 
 }

 public void setId(String id){
  this.id = id;
 }

}
```

But it's failing with spring SpEL exceptions, saying that '!' is invalid. Can someone please help me out get the condition right?

Comment: Another approach using the `conditional` property [can be found here in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74057340/26510)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the variable (argument) is `#req`, so you need `!#req...`.

Second, you need to represent `myStr` as a literal String in SpEL.

Putting it all together...

```
@Cacheable(condition="!#req.id.equals('" + myStr + "')")
```

(Note the single quotes around the value of `myStr`).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you cannot use at first # and then other operator sequentially.
You have to use like -
"#...equals(..) == false"
Or,
"#...equals(..) != true"

Also, best to use as suggested by the first answer by Gary Russell.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I mean to say, # after ! Operator. Thanks